# Fermat's factorisation method

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring

We all know Fermat's factorisation method, but how do we know that the values of $(s-t)$ and $(s+t)$ in the next proof are always primes?

When we say "factorisation" do we always mean the factorisation in primes?

[image]

Comment: They are not always primes. Where does it claim they are?

Comment: No, there is no claim! I ask the question because for all the examples of fermats factorisation method the values of (s-t) and (s+t) are prime. Can I conclude that it's also possible that they aren't?

Comment: Yes, it is even possible that both factors are composite.

Comment: So it's possible that you can't find the prime factorisation of a composite integer by fermats factorisation method?

Comment: The complexity of the Fermat factorization is generally quite poor. It only works well for small numbers or if the number happens to be the product of almost equal factors. In theory, if we apply it repeatedly , it could however complete every factorization.

Comment: @peter So in this case, you should repeat it to prime factor 4?

Comment: $4$ is a bad example because it is not the difference of non-zero-squares, but yes, you can apply it to the factors. Additionally, $4$ is not a prime factor, it is a prime power (in fact, a perfect square)

Comment: Ok I understand it, do you have an other example in which I can clearly see that you have to repeat the proces?

Comment: Take $n=5005$, you get $5005=71^2-6^2=65\cdot 77$

Comment: @LeneCoenen Typically, in textbook examples one is trying to illustrate the method with relatively small numbers.  One also desires to use a number that has no small factors that would be obvious to the reader (to avert the criticism of “why do I need this method when I already can see this factor?”).  These reasons conspire to make it artificially common for the factors to be prime.

Comment: @ErickWong So when we look at RSA, then fermats factorisation method to factor n = pq will always give the two original primes p en q?

Comment: @LeneCoenen Yes.  It may take a long time but it will generally produce non-trivial factors before the trivial one.  Unless you choose $s,t$ to be unusually large, or if one of the two prime factors is $2$.

Comment: @LeneCoenen That's why $p\approx q$ is among the many simple relations that we want to avoid for RSA primes (There are more conditions, each coming from a different factorization "attack" for the important case of numbers with only two prime factors). Maybe it's the attempted attack on RSA that lead you to believe that Fermat works only for $n=pq$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, we don’t distinguish between algorithms for factoring into primes and algorithms for “merely” factoring into two smaller numbers (i.e. non-trivial factors).  There are a few reasonable justifications for this:

1. It is far more common to find an non-trivial algorithm that finds *some* factor rather than exclusively prime factors.  I can only think of trial division as something capable of the latter.
2. In a cryptographic setting, if you can find any non-factor then any system relying on keeping the prime factorization secret would already be considered compromised.  In most scenarios such as RSA, there are only two prime factors in the first place.
3. Once you have a general way to find non-trivial factors, you can just apply that repeatedly to each non-prime factor until you drill down to the prime factors.  This is aided greatly by the fact that it is comparatively very easy to identify when a number is prime.

In the special case of Fermat factorization, it’s a fair point that just because the initial number is easy to factor (on account of being close to a square), it isn’t necessarily the case that the factors will be easy to factor by the same method.  But that doesn’t invalidate the general idea that it isn’t useful to draw a hard line between factoring algorithms and prime-factoring algorithms.